Setup for Websocket using express-ws getting 101 error on live site
I am trying to setup a webSocket connection between two servers (one is being treated as the client in this case, however they are both using node and can handle api calls). When I test it locally it works, but when I push it to my live site I get a 101 error:
Error: Unexpected server response: 101
at ClientRequest. (C:\websites\api\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:912:7)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:631:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:494:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
My server is setup using express-ws:
const app = express();
    const expressWs = require("express-ws");
    expressWs(app);
    
    app.ws("/ws", (ws, req) => {
    //ws code
    }
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`API app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });

My "client" is creating a websocket and using that to make the connection to my server:
Client code:
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const handleWebSocket = (webSocket, label, fileName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "csvFiles", `${fileName}.csv`);

    webSocket.on("open", () => {
      webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ filename: fileName }));

      const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

      readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
        webSocket.send(chunk);
      });

      readStream.on("end", () => {
        console.log(`transfer ${fileName} to ${label}`);
        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ status: "complete" }));
      });

      readStream.on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
        console.log(err);
      });
    });

    webSocket.on("message", (message) => {
      const buffer = Buffer.from(message);
      const decodedString = buffer.toString("utf8");
      console.log(`Message from ${label}: ${decodedString}`);
      if (decodedString === "success") {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Failed to transfer ${fileName} to ${label}`));
      }
    });

    webSocket.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
      console.log(err);
    });

    webSocket.on("close", () => {
      console.log(`Connection to ${label} closed`);
      webSocket.close();
    });
  });
};

const sendFile = (fileName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ws = process?.env?.WEBSOCKET_SERVER
      ? new WebSocket(process.env.WEBSOCKET_SERVER)
      : null;
    const ws_test = process?.env?.WEBSOCKET_TEST_SERVER
      ? new WebSocket(process.env.WEBSOCKET_TEST_SERVER)
      : null;

    const promises = [];
    if (ws) {
      promises.push(
        handleWebSocket(ws, "primary server", fileName).catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Error connecting to primary server: ${error}`);
        })
      );
    }
    if (ws_test) {
      promises.push(
        handleWebSocket(ws_test, "test server", fileName).catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Error connecting to test server: ${error}`);
        })
      );
    }

    // Use Promise.allSettled to handle all promises
    Promise.allSettled(promises)
      .then(() => {
        // Unlink the file regardless of the connection results
        const filePath = path.join(
          __dirname,
          "..",
          "csvFiles",
          `${fileName}.csv`
        );
        fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err); // Reject the main promise if there's an error deleting the file
          } else {
            resolve("completed"); // Resolve the main promise if the file is deleted successfully
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
};

Again, this all works locally but not at all when on my live site.

Where is the client code? You posted your server code, but the error was raised on the client side.

I have added my client code. I assumed the issue is with my server because I only have the issue when I push it up to my live site. I am using Apache with the CPanel interface, although I dont know much about this.

Then this may just as likely be an Apache misconfiguration.

Any direction on how to configure Apache using CPanel? Or how to check if its configured correctly?

Where is your Apache config? :D Please take a moment and read How do I ask a good question?
